# AdMob close my project immediately in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I added google AdMob to my project but now my project is not working. When I try to open my app, it close immediately*

**I used this :**

[https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhf1u.png)

*I couldnt handle this*

*This is YellowWarning*

[image]

Comment: on closing app you should get the pop up explaining runtime error under "view summary" can you share that so that error is more clear.

Comment: it says nothing just closing app, there is no red screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your androidManifest.xml >> inside the `application` tag >> 
Add your Admob ApplicationID into a meta tag like this:

```
<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
           android:value="<YourAdMobApplicationID"/>
```

Comment: I use first time admob,  should I create adMobApplicationID ?

Comment: yes ... you should create an account ... then you should create an application there .. and then the Id of your application should be available in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Thx so much bro it worked !. But it gives me an warning  i put that warning my post can u check that please

Comment: The warning has to do with the internal implementation of the module I guess ... you could hide it by calling `console.disableYellowBox = true;` in your App.js file